# R Download csv from url

Tags: r, csv, url, download

I'm trying to download a csv file from this url https://pip.ipex.it/PipWa/Front/GetCsv.

When I use the following method:

```
url <- "https://pip.ipex.it/PipWa/Front/GetCsv"
destfile <- "C://jamesbrown/pipx.csv"
download.file(url, destfile)
```

Then I get this message:

```
trying URL 'https://pip.ipex.it/PipWa/Front/GetCsv'
Content type 'text/csv' length unknown
downloaded 0 bytes
```

I've also tried in this other way:

```
a<-read.csv("https://pip.ipex.it/PipWa/Front/GetCsv")
```

But this is what I get:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
no lines available in input
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: It's a  null csv file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the link you provided, it is an empty csv. Therefore, I think there are two solutions:

1. you need to specific csv name. then the link should be  https://pip.ipex.it/PipWa/Front/GetCsv/name.csv
2. you need access to the csv in URL. It look like the link need to login first.